# d3.js example "gradient that follows a stroke" from mbostock does not work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, d3.js, gradient, stroke

We use in our project d3.js and the "gradient that follows a stroke" like in this example:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4163057 but it doesn't work as expected in Firefox. Then we discovered -  it is only a problem in firefox... To visualize the problem and for easier understanding I changed the draw points in the example and these are the results:

[image]

Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: This sounds more like an issue for the [d3.js bug tracker](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues) IMHO

Comment: My first thought was that it is not a problem in d3 but a more general Firefox problem to workaround.

Comment: What exactly is wrong? On a Mac, at least, [Safari](http://f.cl.ly/items/3k2s253g202p0z2H200s/safari.png) and [Firefox](http://f.cl.ly/items/3X2g0O2r0O1W0c3p0C3F/firefox.png) look the same

Comment: the bow in the example works fine but change the points to: var points = [
    [86, 388],
    [805, 447],
    [788, 40],
    [93, 72]
]; With the newest Firefox it looks like in the picture i posted

Comment: @wonderb0lt answer from mbostock on d3 issue tracker: It sounds like a bug in Firefox to me but I don’t have time at the moment to investigate.  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2459